# how to move configuration from one Nexus interface to another?

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus

I am doing some cleanup on a Nexus switch I have (3048) and was wondering if there was an easy way to copy or move a configuration from one interface to another? When I move an existing connection to a new physical port, I'd love to avoid configuring the new port -- instead, I want to copy (or move) the configuration from the old port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Configuring the new port" is your only option. I just cut-n-paste the configuration from the old port to the new port. You may have to clear / default the old port first. (and maybe the new one.) And change whatever configuration(s) that might have referenced the old port.

If you have to rearrange a large number of ports, and a reload isn't out of the question, copy the configuration off the switch, edit it, and copy it back as the startup config. (I've done this with many different types of devices.)

Comment: I was afraid this was the only way. I was hoping I was missing a more clever solution. This would be a really nice feature to have, IMHO. It would help for my present use case, but it would also help when adding new devices that should use the same configuration as existing devices.

Comment: Cisco wants you buy their management platforms for that. (ACI, DNA, etc. can "easily" apply templates to many ports, across many systems.)

Comment: Yeah, that seems like the reason that straightforward, helpful tools wouldn't be implemented. Tools like that are WAY overkill for my small environment. I've already moved some of the ports, and it's honestly not bad at all. I was really hoping for a more elegant solution, but manual copying will be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I as iam ware if only way is configure it manually is the best option . After adding configuration to new poet then delete old configuration .

`Manually configuration is the best option to avoid any network outages`